# How can the mutt shell-escape feature be disabled?

Tags: security, email, shell, mutt

We are thinking of offering mutt for our member's email client. The user's shell is instead the mutt application launched on their `Maildir` folder. It works great so far but one huge problem is the shell-escape feature. This would allow users to execute arbitrary code on the system using shell-builtins.

Is there a way to disable the shell-escape in mutt? Otherwise we are thinking of using Alpine and hope that does not have a shell-escape feature as well.

Answer (score 4):

The specific `shell` that is used in `mutt` is a compile-time option:

```
$ mutt -v | grep -i shell
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
```

You need to recompile `mutt` to use `rbash` as `EXECSHELL` instead of `sh`.
You also need to make sure `rbash` is properly secured, as it is not a complete solution on its own.

Comment: Or use /bin/false as EXECSHELL :)

Comment: Compiling with /bin/false does not allow vi or any editor to run

Comment: Another option is simply confining mutt in a chroot jail. Then the shell-builtins are no longer a threat. Any opinions on anything? Thanks